# SASS - @use/@forward and external stylesheets

Tags: sass

In the past I have used and seen @import be used to bring in an external stylesheet (i.e. `@import url(https://unpkg.com/normalize.css@7.0.0/normalize.css)`).

Going forward with @use and @forward it appears you can no longer bring in an external stylesheet? The following statements result in the following errors:

```
@use 'https://unpkg.com/normalize.css@7.0.0/normalize.css';
```

Error: Can't find stylesheet to import.

```
@use url('https://unpkg.com/normalize.css@7.0.0/normalize.css');
```

Error: Expected string.

I'll continue to research but does anyone know if using/forwarding an external stylesheet be possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before Sass modules the @import rule was responsible for both import sass members (variables, functions, and mixins) and plain css.

Today @use and @forward are used to load Sass members, while you can still use @import for plain css, from the docs:

"Because @import is also defined in CSS, Sass needs a way of compiling plain CSS @imports without trying to import the files at compile time. To accomplish this, and to ensure SCSS is as much of a superset of CSS as possible, Sass will compile any @imports with the following characteristics to plain CSS imports:

- Imports where the URL ends with .css.
- Imports where the URL begins http:// or https://.
- Imports where the URL is written as a url().
- Imports that have media queries."

https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/import